# How to handle native exception in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, exception

I want to handle native exception in react-native application. I'm currently using the [react-native-exception-handler](https://github.com/master-atul/react-native-exception-handler) module to do this. All things are working fine except callback. If you read about given module api you will find `setNativeExceptionHandler()` method having three parameters i.e., exceptionhandler, forceAppQuit and executeDefaultHandler.

Here is usage about the method:-

```
// ADVANCED use case:
const exceptionhandler = exceptionString => {
  // this block not executing 
};

setNativeExceptionHandler(
  exceptionhandler,
  false
);
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you tried that it doesn't work?

Comment: I've tried to crash the application by calling the function which does not exist in the application. I've tested in the release build. This is only showing the pop up message when i'm clicking on the relaunch and quit button callback not firing. I'm going to add some more detail in the question please see.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that you are not using it in bundle mode.

From the docs:

> NOTE: setNativeExceptionHandler only works in bundled mode - it will show the red screen when applied to dev mode.

So you should try to build app and then try it.

Also be aware that some actions are not allowed when native exception is happening for ex. you can't use `alert`

From docs:

> NOTE: alert or showing any UI change via JS WILL NOT WORK in case of NATIVE ERRORS.

Comment: Edison, We are using bundle mode. It is working fine but i have an issue with its callback. Just want to clear the app storage when native error occurs. Could you please help me in this?